# Leaflet showing incorrect labels

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am new to R-shiny and leaflet. I'm working on the air crash dataset. I want that user should be able to select a particular year using the slider and the map should show the location of that aircrash. I'm also trying to add a popup that once the user clicks on that, the marker should show the location and summary of that air crash. But for some reason, it is showing the wrong location. For example, when I choose 1908 which is the first record of my dataset, the location of the first record in Virginia, US but it shows Ukraine which is the location of the last record (2020).
[image]
The first record (1908) is Virginia
[image]
The last record (2020) is Ukraine
[image]

My UI code for leaflet is:

```
tabPanel("Aircrash Mapper", leafletOutput('map',width = "100%", height = 900),

             absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                           draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                           width = 330, height = "auto",
                 sliderInput("YrsInput", "Year:", min=min(aircrash_geocoded$crash_year), max=max(aircrash_geocoded$crash_year), 
                             value=2017),
                 
             )
         ),
```

```
 d6<- reactive({
        aircrash_geocoded %>%
            filter(crash_year == input$YrsInput)
        
    })
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({ 
        leaflet() %>% 
            addTiles() %>% 
            addCircles(data = d6(), lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
                       popup = paste("Crash Country:", aircrash_geocoded$crash_country,"<br>",
                                     "Crash Area:", aircrash_geocoded$crash_area, "<br>",
                                     "Summary:", aircrash_geocoded$summary))
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code for the `popup` parameter appears to reference the full dataset, rather than the filtered one. Did you have to do something like d6()$crash_country instead... or some equivalent to show the filtered entry?

Comment: You're right it should have been d6()$crash_country and so on. Thanks for the quick response. I'll update it.